# Is it possible to have ASP Menuitems on opposite sides of the menu?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a basic ASP:Menu in a Div.
I have four asp:menuitem's in the menu.
Is it possible to have three items on the left and one on the right?

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Comment"/>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/refurb.aspx" Text="Refurb">
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Account/MembersOnly.aspx" Text="Members Only"/>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

I tried making two asp:Menu's inside one Div with the CSS having 'float:right;'
 
but it just put the fourth menu item on the next line down on the right side.

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Comment"/>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="http://moduletestweb/refurb" Text="Refurb Website">   </asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu2" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Account/MembersOnly.aspx" Text="Members Only"/>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</div>

/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu2
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
    float: right;
}

div.menu2 ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 99%;
    float: right;
}

div.menu2 ul li a, div.menu2 ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: right;
}

div.menu2 ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
}

div.menu2 ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
}
```

I feel like I am going about this the wrong way
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to first menu.

You can add it as inline style to both menus `style="float:left"` for first menu and `style="float:right"` for second menu so you don't have to duplicate CSS to create menu2 class.

Comment: Though that makes it a lot less messy (thank you). The last menu item is still dropped to another line below the other items.

Comment: I've just checked it and it seems that in IE menu is rendered as table while in Chrome it is a div. Above solution works in IE but not in Chrome. I think the best way to make sure you get menu on each edge of the screen is to put them into table that has width = 100% with one row and 2 columns and set text align for each column.

Comment: What do you mean by "one row and 2 columns"?
I just got it to work but it's kind of messy.
I used the two separate menus and for menu2 I put !important after float:right then used the margin and padding to adjust it. It looks okay in IE and Chrome so far.

Comment: <table width="100%"><tr><td align="left">Menu1 here</td><td align="right">Menu2 here</td></tr><table>

Comment: That seems to make the menu background take over the whole body section.